# How do I estimate how much bandwidth my web scraper uses?

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, puppeteer

I'm looking into web scraping proxy tools and am interested in Smart Proxy. The thing that concerns me is that I'll pay by bandwidth and I don't have any idea how much bandwidth my web scraper uses. Is there a way for me to estimate this before I sign up for the service?

Maybe something simple like manually loading the web pages and inspecting something in chrome dev tools?

Comment: have you tried bandwhich ?

Comment: @pguardiario thanks for the recommendation, it wasn't super clear how to use bandwhich so I just signed up for the service and ran a few tests to see how much bandwidth my scrapers were using. Thanks again for the suggestion, though.